# C return struct from function

Tags: c++

```
typedef struct
{
    int hours;
} Time;

Time addTime(Time time1, Time time2)
{
    Time time;

    time = time1.hours + time2.hours;

    return time;
}
```

How to do if I want to return time as a struct? I tried this way but I get a loooot of errors.

`error: no match for 'operator=' in 'time = (time1.Time::hours + time2.Time::hours)'`

`note: Time& Time::operator=(const Time&)`

`no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const Time&'`

Comment: From the error messages I conclude this is C++.

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
 time = time1.hours + time2.hours;
```

by

```
 time.hours = time1.hours + time2.hours;
```

or starting from C99 just initialize it at declaration time:

```
Time time = {time1.hours + time2.hours};
```

Please also notice you tagged the question as C but you are using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @user2985179 C and C++ are two different languages, you should not do that.

Comment: @user2985179 yes, but I promise it will bite you.

Comment: @user2985179: "working like a charm" means nothing, possibly less. Use a C compiler to compile C code.

Answer (score 0):

@Ouah gave a perfectly valid answer - I just want to illuminate one aspect that didn't yet come up.

In the example you give, the `struct` is very small - a single `int`. Usually, you use a `struct` because you have a number of related fields that "belong together"; there is a performance penalty for returning such a `struct` from a function, because it will make a copy of all the elements on the stack. It would be preferable to call your function with *pointers* to the structures - both for the inputs, and for the return value. It might look something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int hours;
} Time;

void addTime(Time *time1, Time *time2, Time *sumTime)
{

    sumTime->hours = time1->hours + time2->hours;

}
```

And you would call it with:

```
time1.hours = 4;
time2.hours = 5;
Time totalTime;
addTime(&time1, &time2, &totalTime);
printf("The total time is %d hours\n", totalTime.hours);
```

Note - in your case, an `int` is smaller than a pointer, so your code is more efficient (with the bug fixed). However, for any "practical" struct, the above method is likely to yield a performance benefit.

Comment: Agree. I prefer to pass structures by pointers but in this case you should alway be careful and use "const" word to pretend undesired changes.